# matrix-js-sdk get all messages from room

Tags: javascript, matrix, sdk

How do you get all the messages from a room in matrix?

I am following
https://matrix.org/docs/guides/usage-of-the-matrix-js-sdk

I have the client started and synchronized.

Accessing room.timeline only gives the most recent messages. I want to get all of from the beginning of the chat.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `initialRoomSync` function from the SDK and access the `messages` attribute to get the entire timeline of messages, then you can listen for new ones by listening to the `Room.timeline` event as described on the documentation you have provided.

Comment: it's `roomInitialSync`, not `roomInitialSync` by the way

Comment: @jan you have a typo. Should be it's `roomInitialSync`, not `initialRoomSync`